# Duplicate in inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to join a table with itself and then sum over 4 weeks. Below is the sample data

| TIN | Direction | amount | B_date | TransactionID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | CASHIN | 8750 | 2021-07-06 | 182 |
| 106 | CASHIN | 8750 | 2021-08-05 | 183 |

When I am trying to join the table with itself to sum all the amounts for same TIN within 4 weeks. I am getting a duplicate row. As per the table sum should have been 17500 but the sum I am getting is 26250. Below is the code that I developed

```
Select 
    sub.TIN as TIN,
    sub.Direction as Direction,
    sum(sub.amount) as Sum_Amt,
    min(sub.B_Date) as From_Date,
    max(sub.B_Date) as To_Date
from ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin main
join ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin sub on main.TIN = sub.TIN
    and main.B_Date <= sub.B_Date
    and DATEDIFF(wk,main.B_Date,sub.B_Date) <=4
    and sub.TIN = '10627503'
group by sub.TIN, sub.Direction
```

The Output

| TIN | Direction | Sum_amount | From_date | To_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | CASHIN | 26250 | 2021-07-06 | 2021-08-05 |

I tired to check and found there is a duplicate row. Below is the code

```
Select 
    sub.TIN as TIN,
    sub.Direction as Direction,
    sub.amount,
    sub.B_Date,
    sub.TransactionID
from ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin main
join ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin sub on main.TIN = sub.TIN
    and main.B_Date <= sub.B_Date
    and DATEDIFF(wk,main.B_Date,sub.B_Date) <=4
```

The output

| TIN | Direction | amount | B_date | TransactionID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | CASHIN | 8750 | 2021-07-06 | 182 |
| 106 | CASHIN | 8750 | 2021-08-05 | 183 |
| 106 | CASHIN | 8750 | 2021-08-05 | 183 |

The desired output is as below

| TIN | Direction | Sum_amount | From_date | To_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 106 | CASHIN | 17500 | 2021-07-06 | 2021-08-05 |

Thanks!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Which of the output shown above is your desired results?

Comment: @Stu Added the desired output

Comment: @xQbert        I did but it is not giving me the desired output

Comment: "within 4 weeks" from which point in time?

Comment: @sticky bit    from the day when first transaction was made by the same TIN for same direction

Comment: Your expected total is just the sum of both rows, I don't understand why you need to self-join, probably just regular aggregation over a window is the answer but impossible to say without more relevant sample data.

Comment: I think your join logic (and general approach) are flawed. As already suggested it seems you need a simple aggregate with the appropriate window. But to really understand what your query does, remove the aggregates and add the primary key columns of the table so you can actually SEE which rows are joined. That is basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If by "within 4 weeks" you meant "last 4 weeks from now" then the following query would do:

```
select TIN as TIN,
       Direction as Direction,
       sum(amount) as Sum_Amt,
       min(B_Date) as From_Date,
       max(B_Date) as To_Date
  from ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin
 where DATEDIFF(wk, B_Date, getdate()) > 4
```

or, if you need a rolling total then you'd use the following [technique](https://rextester.com/LXJAM36997)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Input and Output

[image]

If so, here's the code:

```
Select 
    sub.TIN as TIN,
    sub.Direction as Direction,
    sum(sub.amount) as Sum_Amt,
    min(sub.B_Date) as From_Date,
    max(sub.B_Date) as To_Date
from ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin main
INNER join ind_cash_trnx_cond_tin sub on main.TIN = sub.TIN
    and main.B_Date = sub.B_Date
    and DATEDIFF(wk,main.B_Date,sub.B_Date) <=4
   -- and sub.TIN = '10627503'
group by sub.TIN,
    sub.Direction,
    sub.amount
```